# using echo command with $ in shell script

Tags: shell, echo

Recently, i used echo command prefixing it with $. To my surprise what it resulted was an error.
My command was something like this.

```
# !/bin/bash
$(echo 'a')
```

The error was..

```
./test1.sh: line 3: a: command not found
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(echo a)` is a "command substitution".  The `$(...)` will be replaced by the *output of the command within*.  The output in this case is `a`, which the shell then tries to execute. The shell can't locate the command called `a` and you get the error message.

It is unclear what your intention with this was or what you expected to happen. It is *highly unusual* to want to execute the result of a command substitution.

---

Some programs output strings that should be evaluated by the shell. It is therefore possible to see code like

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

which evaluates (runs) the output of the given command.  These commands have a strictly specified output and are generally considered safe to run in this way. In the example above, `ssh-agent` will start the SSH agent process and output a few commands that will set the appropriate environment variables that the `ssh` client later will need for using the agent, for example,

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-Ppg1EO5eRIZp/agent.6017; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=6018; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 6018;
```

This is then evaluated by `eval`.

`eval` is used here rather than just simply using `$(ssh-agent)` since the output of the `ssh-agent` command is more a compound command.  Without `eval`, the `;` command terminators would net be special.

Example:

```
$ s='echo hello; echo world'
$ $s
hello; echo world
$ eval "$s"
hello
world
```

Comment: OTOH, `eval "$(dircolors)"` is a reasonable thing to do. Same with several other commands that follow that pattern, like gpg-agent.

Comment: @derobert Yes, and `$(ssh-agent)`. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set -x` to see what the shell is doing:

```
set -x
$(echo 'a')
  ++ echo a
  + a
```

The shell executes `echo a` and puts the output on the command line. This is the same as if you had tried to execute this command line:

```
a
```

The shell looks for a command `a` in the path (and even before in the function, alias, and hash lists), does not find it and thus throws an error.

It works if the output is a valid command:

```
$(echo 'ls')
```

Comment: can you tell me,  what for actually we use $ other then calling a variable.

Comment: @Ashu It is obviously also used for command substitution – your case. Besides it appears in computation (`echo $((1+2+3))`), string creation (`$'foo\nbar'` / `$"foo"`) and (less shell related) in the regexes which `bash` understands (`[[ foo =~ ^f..$ ]]`). It is also used for modifying variables in several ways: `${foo#bar}`